# Unable to start grails war on tomcat6

Tags: java, grails, groovy, tomcat6

I'm getting this in catalina.out when I try to deploy a grails application:

```
Feb 9, 2012 10:32:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 9, 2012 10:32:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/application] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 9, 2012 10:32:25 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Transaction synchronizations]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
Feb 9, 2012 10:32:25 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Prototype beans currently in creation]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
Feb 9, 2012 10:32:25 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Transactional resources]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
Feb 9, 2012 10:32:25 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.MyThreadLocal] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$MyThreadLocal@3872a921]) and a value of type [null] (value [null]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.
```

Running Grails 2.0, Tomcat 6, Ubuntu 10.04. I haven't seen anything like this before, is this something I'm doing / can fix or something with how Tomcat is setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real error will be in another log file in the logs directory. The thread leak messages are a concern, but that's an issue when shutting down. Your failure to startup is the problem and it's not described at all in what you've shown other than `SEVERE: Context [/application] startup failed due to previous errors`

Answer (score 0):

Are you running backgroundthread plugin by any chance? I have seen Tomcat fail to respond because of the plugin which does not give up the thread and prevents the server from shutting down correctly.